# Can we display emoji from keyboard into Linear Layout?

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, emoji

I'm trying to add emojis in a `LinearLayout` but I don't know if it's possible or not. What I want to do is when I press emoji it should appear in a `LinearLayout` rather than `EmojiEditText`. Is it possible?

I have searched for quite a while but I can't find any solution to my problem. Please suggest a library or solution that supports displaying of emojis in `LinearLayout`.

[image: Screenshot of chat-like interface with messages containing hand emojis]

Answer (score 0):

Rather than go for library, You can do from scratch as well. 
Make one Linear layout and append that linear layout as the emoji is pressed.
For that, Give ID to the linear layout and append the layout by adding view to it.

```
LinearLayout linearLayout;


linearLayout = findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);


linearLayoutAmi.addView("VIEW_ACCORDING_TO_EMOJI");
```

Answer (score 0):

Emojis are in text format, and LinearLayout does not have a text property unlike a widget. Wrap each selected emoji in a TextView and then add the textview into the target LinearLayout as child view.